# MaterializeCss : How to enable different checkboxes with JQuery in multiple select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I am having trouble Enabling Check boxes in Select box with multiple attribute. the values are in an array.

```
var values = ["op1","op2","op3","op4"];
```

I want to enable all check boxes which are in array. i cant figure out how to pass values to select. the box is working fine when i give only one value

```
$("#select_box").val(values[0]);
```

here is the fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/dmtv02j8/3/

Comment: Please, share HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparantly you have to call `.material_select2('refresh')`. This is how you can achieve what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var values = ['op1', 'op2'];
    var selectEl = $('select');
    selectEl.material_select();
    selectEl.val(values);
    selectEl.material_select('refresh');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select multiple>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="op1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="op2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="op3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Multiple Select</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass data instead data[0] and it works

```js
  $('#list').material_select(); // initial initialization
  
  
   // data from database via ajax
   var data = ["op1","op2"];
   
   
    $('#list').val(data);
    $('#list').material_select(); // re initalization on data change
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select multiple name="list[]" id="list">

    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
  
    <option value="op1">op1</option>
    <option value="op2">op2</option>
    <option value="op3">op3</option>
    <option value="op4">op4</option>
    <option value="op5">op5</option>

  </select>
  <label style="color:#009688">List Of Category</label>
</div>
```